# TinyMCE: What can I do about multiple textarea performance issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I've got a page with a dynamically-generated form. Normally this form contains a few (1-4) text areas, and I convert them all in to TinyMCE editors with a single `tinyMCE.init()` call.

That works great, but there's a problem: *sometimes* the page has more textareas ... in one instance as many as 79.  When this happens, the page sort of locks up when the TinyMCE initialization starts (the reload/stop button toggles back and forth and you can't do anything).  10 seconds or so later the initialization resolves and the page works fine, but obviously having a locked page for 10 seconds isn't the best user experience.

So, my question is: what options do I have?  Is there any way to load TinyMCE "on the fly" when people click in to the text areas, or otherwise optimize for this extreme case of 79 textareas?

Comment: You must go for a lazy load/init approach, and here you have a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1773492/722135

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm unclear on the details.  If I (for instance) set up an onFocus handler for my textareas which invokes `tinyMCE.init`, I can get the first focused textarea to work with the options `{elements: e.target.id, mode: 'exact'}`, but any subsequent focuses don't initialize TinyMCE.  Can you (or anyone) point me towards an example or some rough code or any sort of "prior art" for doing this sort of TinyMCE lazy loading?

Comment: The official site has a demo for load on demand, which is similar as your need: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/load_on_demand.php

Comment: I solved my problem by using `selector` instead of `elements`/`mode`, and then your link was helpful too.  Thanks.